# Wpf webbrowser, how to detect when it tries to download?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

When you use the C#.Net wpf WebBrowser control to view html pages, and the user clicks on a link to a file with an unknown extension, the webbrowser tries to download this file.

On systems with no pdf viewer installed, webbrowser tries to download pdf files instead of either displaying them or warning the user that they need Adobe, etc.

I would like to detect when a webbrowser tries to download, so I can check if the file is pdf and then provide a download link.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the Navigated and LoadCompleted events and checking the URL there?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268220(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Navigated doesn't fire when the link is in the currently displayed page. When a link to a file is clicked, LoadComplete eventargs contains the previous valid html page, not the file link. "FileDownload" is in the Windows Forms control, not the WPF control.