# Detect when a click downloads a file in winforms WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a simple webpage with only 3 links displayed in my webbrowser component:

```
<a href="/newpage1.html" id="el-1">Go to new page 1</a>
<a href="/newpage2.html" id="el-2">Go to new page 2</a>
<a href="/file.zip" id="el-1">Download file</a>
```

I register an event handler for the click event on a list of elements

```
foreach (HtmlElement e in this.webBrowserMain.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")){
    e.Click += this.SingleElementClickHandler;
}
```

Let's assume that server side the following headers are sent for the file /file.zip

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
```

How can I write the SingleElementClickHandler to pop up a message box with the text "Hello" when a file is downloaded and **not** when another web page is opened?

I can't use any third party component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
this.webBrowserMain.FileDownload += 
    new EventHandler((x, y) => MessageBox.Show("Hello"));
```

Found this after a bit more of search [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927909/wpf-webbrowser-how-to-detect-when-it-tries-to-download) SO question (even if it is wpf component and not winforms component).